# How to make d3 gauge chart responsive?

Tags: angular, d3.js

Can anyone help me to resize the d3 gauge chart? 
Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-gauge-chart) code.

I've tried,

```
.attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet")
```

and

```
window.addEventListener("resize", this.draw);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please modify your render() and add

```
        svg = d3.select(container)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('class', 'gauge')
      .attr('width', '100%')
      .attr('height', '100%')
      .attr('viewBox', '0' + ' ' + '0'+ ' ' + config.clipWidth + ' ' + config.clipHeight)
     .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMin')
```