# Scale d3 chart in different resolutions

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

We have a requirement of creating a dashboard in angular where I am using a gauge chart code from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-gauge-chart).

My HTML file looks something like this:

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center" >
<div fxFlex='33%'>
    <div id="power-gauge"></div>
</div>
<div fxFlex='33%'>
    <!-- Some other chart -->
</div>
<div fxFlex='33%'>
    <!-- Some other chart -->
</div>
```

Now the issue is when the website is being accessed from different resolutions this gauge is not scaling properly as it has a static height and width.

Is there any way I can make it responsive.

Comment: Have you seen this post before  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659198/how-to-make-d3-gauge-chart-responsive    ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to give `height` and `width` in `%`.Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659198/how-to-make-d3-gauge-chart-responsive).